# Quasi-isomorphic doesn't induce homeomorphic example

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

[image]

Can someone please explain this example? It’s not clear why it doesn’t induce homeomorphism. Does anyone have any simpler example?

Comment: The standard example of quasi-isometric, non-homeomorphic metric spaces is: the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is quasi-isometric to the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What about two finite spaces of different cardinalities with the discrete metric?

Comment: @DerekHolt That also works of course - or indeed *any* two bounded metric spaces!

Comment: @NoahSchweber 
Can you please provide some more details. Why Z^2 and R^2 are not homeomorphic?

Comment: @matan Um, $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't? $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ isn't? There are lots of reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Quasi-isometry is really a tool for studying the *large-scale* structure of a metric space. It's completely insensitive to fine details. In particular, *any* two bounded metric spaces are quasi-isometric, via *any* map from one to the other (this is a good exercise).

So pick two bounded complete CAT(0) spaces with different $\partial$s. For example, the interval $[0, 1]$ and the square $[0, 1]^2$.